# What is the best way to multiply arrays? in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays.

```
Array1 
[[-0.23,  0.11],  
[0.29, -0.37]]

Array2 
([5.28, 4.40])
```

I want to do sum the multiplication of one array by the other

Example

- sum(5.28 *-0.23 + 4.40 * 0.11) = ind1
- sum(5.28 *-0.29 + 4.40 * -0.37) = ind2

df

```
 -0.7304
 -3.1592
```

Comment: Your example calculation is incorrect, you use `-0.29` instead of `0.29` in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with how to [create numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.creation.html) and [multiply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) them?

```
numpy.matmul(Array1, Array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.dot` [does not use broadcasting, see comments]:

```
A = np.array([[-0.23,  0.11],  
              [0.29, -0.37]])

B = np.array([5.28, 4.40])

res = np.dot(A, B)
# or res = A @ B

array([-0.7304, -0.0968])
```

Comment: Actually, `dot` doesn't do broadcasting.

Comment: @hpaulj, Oh oops, can you explain what it does then here? I mean, does it manually copy the values to multiply for each row? [seems inefficient]

Comment: As far as I know, the arrays are passed to compiled (BLAS) code that does it's own iteration at C level.  It's ends up being the equivalent of `(A*B).sum(1)`, but is much faster.  The formal broadcasting rules (which we've explained elsewhere) don't apply to `dot` or `matmul`.

Comment: @hpaulj, OK, got it. Well, it would be interesting to see a broadcasting-based solution (esp if it's faster).

Comment: Does not look like it's faster (and it's probably also more memory-hungry): `%timeit np.dot(a, b)` -> 1.5 µs, while `%timeit (a[..., None] * b[None, ...]).sum(1)` -> 15 µs (for `a = np.random.random((20, 10))` and `b = np.random.random((10, 30))`)

Comment: @norok2, While your point may be correct, timing on such small arrays prove nothing, these are microseconds and can be dominated by function calls, etc. You need larger errors to demonstrate the difference.